# How to select records with zero associations from two has_many?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following models:

```rb
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :departure, class_name: 'Stop'
  belongs_to :arrival, class_name: 'Stop'
end
```

```rb
class Stop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :departure_reports, foreign_key: 'departure_id', class_name: 'Report'
  has_many :arrival_reports, foreign_key: 'arrival_id', class_name: 'Report'
end
```

These are the corresponding migrations:

```rb
class CreateReports < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :reports do |t|
      t.references :departure, foreign_key: { to_table: :stops }
      t.references :arrival, foreign_key: { to_table: :stops }

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class CreateStops < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :stops do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

How to select `stops` that don't have any associated `report` as `departure` or `arrival` ?

Comment: What Rails version are you using? How do the migrations of Report and Stop look like?

Comment: I'm using Rails 5

Comment: I also added the corresponding migrations in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `joins` to define your own `left outer join` by checking the rows in the `stops` table that match by their id with the `departure_id` and/or `arrival_id` in the `reports` table.

After that, a `where` clause can be used to filter those reports where the `departure_id` or `arrival_id` are `NULL`:

```
Stop
  .joins('left outer join reports on stops.id IN (reports.departure_id, reports.arrival_id)')
  .where('reports.departure_id IS NULL OR reports.arrival_id IS NULL')
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work:

`Stop.left_joins(:departure_reports, :arrival_reports).where('reports.departure_id is null or reports.arrival_id is null').count
# == 75`

`Stop.all.select(& -> (stop) { stop.departure_reports.count + stop.arrival_reports.count == 0 }).count
# == 74`

Comment: In this example there are 76 `Stop`s and 1 `Report` in the database. The report's `departure` and `arrival` are two different `Stop`s.

Comment: The one that is not selected is the arrival.

Comment: Do you have an extract of those records? Or easier a repository for this? I tried replicating your scenario, don't know if I omitted something.

Comment: As per your question _how to select stops that don't have any associated report as departure or arrival ?_ this should work `Stop.joins('left outer join reports on stops.id IN (reports.departure_id, reports.arrival_id)').where('reports.departure_id IS NULL OR reports.arrival_id IS NULL')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
class Stop
  scope :without_reports, -> {
    where(_not_exists(Report.where("stops.id IN (departure_id, arrival_id)")))
  }

  def self._not_exists(scope)
    "NOT EXISTS(#{scope.to_sql})"
  end
end
```

replace `NOT EXISTS` with `EXISTS` to get stops with reports

```
> Stop.without_reports
SELECT "stops".* FROM "stops" WHERE (NOT EXISTS(SELECT "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE (stops.id IN (departure_id, arrival_id))))
```

Comment: In the `where`, where does `stops.id` come from?

Comment: added sql to the answer. `_not_exists ` method is converting the `Report.where...` to sql string.