# How to select records with zero associations from two nested has_many?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Some days ago I asked the following question: [How to select records with zero associations from two has many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58356914/how-to-select-records-with-zero-associations-from-two-has-many)

I failed to adapt the answer that solved my previous question to this similar situation:

```rb
class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :departure, class_name: 'Stop'
  belongs_to :arrival, class_name: 'Stop'
end
```

```rb
class Stop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :departure_reports, foreign_key: 'departure_id', class_name: 'Report'
  has_many :arrival_reports, foreign_key: 'arrival_id', class_name: 'Report'
  belongs_to :journey
end
```

```rb
class Journey < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stops
end
```

These are the corresponding migrations:

```rb
class CreateReports < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :reports do |t|
      t.references :departure, foreign_key: { to_table: :stops }
      t.references :arrival, foreign_key: { to_table: :stops }

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class CreateStops < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :stops do |t|
      t.references :journey, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class CreateJourneys < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :journeys do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is a more visual description:

[image]

How to select `journeys` whose `stops` don't have any associated `report` as `departure` or `arrival` ?

What I'm looking for would be equivalent to this:

```rb
Journey.all.select do |journey|
  journey.stops.all? do |stop|
    stop.departure_reports.count + stop.arrival_reports.count == 0
  end
end
```

**Edit**

Trying the solution proposed by Sebastian Palma:

```rb
Journey
  .left_joins(:stops)
  .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN reports ON stops.id IN (reports.departure_id, reports.arrival_id)')
  .where(reports: { departure_id: nil, arrival_id: nil })
```

I get the following sql query:

```sql
SELECT "journeys".* FROM "journeys"
LEFT OUTER JOIN reports ON stops.id IN (reports.departure_id, reports.arrival_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN "stops" ON "stops"."journey_id" = "journeys"."id"
WHERE "reports"."departure_id" IS NULL AND "reports"."arrival_id" IS NULL
LIMIT $1 [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

With this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "stops")
LINE 1: ...eys".* FROM "journeys" LEFT OUTER JOIN reports ON stops.id I...
                                                             ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have following model side changes,

```
class Journey < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stops
  has_many :departure_reports, through: :stops
  has_many :arrival_reports, through: :stops
end
```

And get journeys having both

```
Journey.where.not(id: Journey.joins(:departure_reports, :arrival_reports).distinct.ids)
```

Good part of above is, only single query is fired even inner attributes are passed by calling another query.

Comment: I did something similar for testing, but I would prefer a pure SQL solution

Comment: @JulienDargelos Above query is activerecord query which make SQL at back-end. Did you give a try to it?

Comment: Oh, yes you're right, I thought "above" meant "the answer above" (it was above yours just now)

Comment: @JulienDargelos I thought you know exact difference between 'pure SQL solution' & 'activerecord query'.

Comment: Never said I did, tell me

Comment: @JulienDargelos *I did something similar for testing, but I would prefer a pure SQL solution* but trying activerecord solution in edited question.

Comment: I used to think that nesting activerecord queries (not the case of my edited question) involves sequential sql queries, so I thought it was the same for your solution. By pure SQL solution I meant a solution that doesn't imply to resolve a subquery through ruby before resolving the main one (but I agree, your solution doesn't, I just didn't pay enough attention and got confused by the "above" thing).

Comment: @JulienDargelos Main objective you must see, is reducing time complexity which will be obtained by using single sql query. And next should be code complexity. You can prefer `Arel` used for complex queries.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that's why I try to avoid multiple SQL queries when only one is sufficient (and why I mistakenly rejected your answer). If by "code complexity" you mean "cognitive complexity", your solution is definitively the best right now since it is very meaningful.